# Obtaining list of installed OSGI bundles at runtime

Tags: osgi, equinox

My application obtains class names from a properties file. Classes represented by these class names could reside in certain OSGI bundles unknown at advance so in order to instantiate them I firstly have to find which bundle these classes belong to. I'm thinking about getting all installed bundles from BundleContext#getBundles, this means I have to obtain reference to BundleContext in AbstractUIPlugin#start. But I'm not sure if holding reference to BundleContext is the right thing to do since it's should be used only in the start method. So I need advice from OSGI experts here about the alternatives to get list of bundles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Setya

Comment: why are you instantiating classes in OSGi? Declare them as a service and have Equinox handle their lifecycle.  Do you have a specific reason to do so?

Answer (score 5):

This is not really how OSGi is intended. If a bundle has something to add to the 'global' context, you should register a service. So each bundle that has something to share can do that in its own start method.

Some other component (DS, ServiceTracker, Blueprint, something like that) can then listen to these events, and act accordingly.

This is really important, if you start manually searching through all bundles you completely lose the advantages of OSGi.

Answer (score 1):

Like written before you should try to use services to achieve what you want. I guess you have an Interface with one or more implementations that should be installable at runtime. So if you control the bundles that implement the interface then simply let them install their implementation as a service by using an Activator or a blueprint context. You can use service properties to describe your implementation.

The bundles that need the implementation can then lookup the services using a service tracker or a service reference in blueprint.

If that is not possible then you can use the bundle context to obtain the running bundles and instantiate the classes but this is not how OSGi should work. You will run into classloading problems as the bundle that tries to instantiate the classes will not have direct access to them.

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle gets control at start up through the bundle activator, or better, through DS. At that time it can register services with the services registry so others can find/use them.

The route your planning to go (properties that name classes) is evil since you undoubtedly will run in class loading hell. Modularity is about hiding your implementation details, the name of your implementation classes are such details.

Exposing implementation classes in properties files is really bad practice and it looses the advantage of modularity. It does not matter if another class refers to your implementation class or a property file, the problem is that the impl. class is exposed.

Unfortunately this model has become so prevalent in our industry that many developers think it is normal :-(

OSGi allows you share instances typed by interfaces in a way that allows the implementation class to only be known inside the module.